# jQuery scope or race condition in AJAX/getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, timing

I have a piece of jQuery code which invokes several `getJSON()` calls in quick succession:

```
var table = $("table#output");
for (var i in items) {
    var thisItem = items[i];
    $.getJSON("myService", { "itemID": thisItem }, function(json) {
        var str = "<tr>";
        str += "<td>" + thisItem + "</td>";
        str += "<td>" + json.someMember + "</td>";
        str += "</tr>";
        table.append(str);
    });
}
```

When I run this against a laggy server, the table gets populated with the expected `json.someMember` values (they arrive out of order: I don't mind that), but the `thisItem` column is populated with an unpredictable mixture of values from various iterations.

I'm assuming this is something to do with scope and timing - the callback function is reading `thisItem` from a wider scope? Am I right? How do I prevent this?

My current workaround is for the JSON service to return a copy of its inputs - which is unsatisfying to say the least.

Comment: Thanks Slim for asking this question. I also had some issues (I was aware of the asynchronous function returns but not sure how to signal the getJSON call back what location to place a return value).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems like a scoping issue due to the loop. Try this:

```
var table = $("table#output");
for (var i in items) {
    var thisItem = items[i];
    $.getJSON("myService", { "itemID": thisItem }, (function(thisItem) {
        return function(json) {
            var str = "<tr>";
            str += "<td>" + thisItem + "</td>";
            str += "<td>" + json.someMember + "</td>";
            str += "</tr>";
            table.append(str);
        }
    })(thisItem));
}
```

*Edit*: all I did was scope `thisItem` to the `$.getJSON` callback.

Comment: I don't think this would work with jQuery. Wouldn't the json end up getting passed into the closure instead of the thisItem variable and cause an error?

Comment: No. $.getJSON gets passed the inner function; the one that does get the "json" parameter.

Comment: Seems to have worked a treat (after I got all the braces sorted!). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Crescent Fresh, had to pass in the index for the image table I wanted to populate (got burned by asynchronous returns, even though I knew about them wasn't sure how to scope it). Passing the index worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Javascript does not use block for scope. Scope is only based on functions.

If you want a new scope, you have to declare a new internal function and run it immediately, this is the only way to create a new scope in Javascript.

```
var table = $("table#output");
for( var i in items ) 
{
    (function(){
        var thisItem = items[i];
        $.getJSON("myService", { "itemID": thisItem }, function(json) 
        {
            var str = "<tr>";
            str += "<td>" + thisItem + "</td>";
            str += "<td>" + json.someMember + "</td>";
            str += "</tr>";
            table.append(str);
        });
    })();
}
```

Comment: I like this solution since it allows me to have more local variables like thisItem, without a verbose function signature.

Comment: fun fact: this is how scoping is usually implemented in Scheme

Comment: I forgot another way, you could use a for loop from a library, these actually take a function as the block to execute at each iteration. In jQuery: $.each(items, function(i, item){ ... });

Comment: Thanks a bunch Vincent. I was getting burned by scope on asynchronous callbacks. encapsulated a passed index to know where to put my returns and whala!